# I recently upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 on 2 laptops.

Tags: browser

I can't bring up a browser on 22.04 on one laptop.  Everything was fine before I upgraded from 20.04.  Now, Firefox, Chromium, and Falkon don't work.  Nothing will come up.

Comment: You need to provide much more information. For example, what happens when you try to start these browsers from command line? Do you have the same problem when you try with a newly created user? Please, [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: How do I start them from command line?  I'm a novice.  When I click on the browser icon, it acts like it's opening, but nothing shows up.  In the launcher, when I hover the mouse arrow over the icon, it shows blank.  Nothing actually comes up on the screen.  I installed 22.04 on another laptop, and it works fine.  But on the Dell, I simply can't bring up a browser.

Comment: `$ firefox ` + `Enter` from Terminal / Bash / Command line (shortcut to open: CTRL+ALT+T,  close: CTRL+D ) - - -  Copy text by marking it with the mouse, hit CTRL+SHIFT+C to copy. Paste with CTRL+V in your post above, mark the text and click `{ }` to make it appear as "code".